# Wrong result using POST method

Tags: http, post, postman, form-data

Can't seem to get the right result using POST method.

I'm trying to access the "MATRICULE" page on this website https://servicesenligne2.ville.montreal.qc.ca/sel/evalweb/index

This is what the response looks like :

[image]

[image]

However, I always end up on the "SEARCH BY ADDRESS" page. Here's the result I get with POSTMAN.

[image]

Any ideas why this might happen ?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to enable key-value of form-data

[image]

Comment: Would have been nice. But I disabled it to test something haha. Enabling it doesn't change anything.